# get the latest windows Startup Login event data from event viewer using c#?

Tags: c#, linq, windows-services, windows-security, event-viewer

i am getting all information from windows security log and event viewer related to logon and logg off but i want only latest loggon event info from all information can you please apply some linq on that to get the top most Startup Login event info

here is my code what i am trying

```
      EventLog log = new EventLog()
        {
            Source = "Microsoft Windows security auditing.",
            Log = "Security"
        };
      foreach (EventLogEntry entry in log.Entries)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(entry.Message);
        }
```

can you make any foreach in lambda base to get only logon event that is the latest one

Comment: The latest event is always : `log.Entries[log.Entries.Count - 1];`. You don't need foreach for that,

Comment: but only log on its giving log off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample to get the latest "Logon (4624)" and "Special Logon (4672)"

```
  var log = new EventLog
  {
    Source = "Microsoft Windows security auditing.",
    Log = "Security"
  };
  var latestLogon =
    log.Entries.Cast<EventLogEntry>()
      .Where(entry => entry.InstanceId == 4624 || entry.InstanceId == 4672)
      .OrderByDescending(i => i.TimeWritten)
      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: DO YOU HAVE A LINK HOW TO START SERVICE AUTOMATICALLY ON PC RESTART ON LOGON C#

Comment: Probably this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477618/how-do-i-change-a-windows-services-startup-type-in-net-post-install

Comment: done got it [start service on win login link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089601/run-the-application-at-windows-startup)

Comment: but the above code requires admin permission any solution for that on start up how to open run as on that function

Comment: No, you need Admin to access "log.Entries".

Comment: [same prob part link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410458/execute-specific-function-with-admistrator-preveligies-c) the link is to similar prob log enteris admin permission . how

Comment: You need to add app.manifest like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator or start your visual studio using "run as administrator". Otherwise not possible.

Comment: IF I ADD APP CONFIG FILE  LOGGIN FUNCTION NOT WORKS and if i use visual studio as admin what about my loggin event that is registered in registery to start on win start

Comment: login event is in registery to start app automatically on win session login

Comment: I dont understand what you want. Not app.config, but app.manifest.

Comment: Read that article carefully, not only add app.manifest, but you must change a line in that app.manifest `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

Comment: If you are creating windows service, then set it as Local System Account, read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13082284/how-do-i-give-my-windows-service-admin-rights